# onClick being able to populate modal and submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my onClick action to submit information (in other words, call a function) and also generate a modal.

I have:

```
 <Button  onClick = {this.showModal('small')}>Generate Channel Information</Button>
```

which generates the modal

or I use this to generate the function:

```
 <Button  onClick = {this.generateInfo)}>Generate Channel Information</Button>
```

but I can't seem to do both. Any ideas how I can do 2 things with onClick?

Answer (score 1):

just have a function that calls your other functions

`onClick = {() => { this.generateInfo(); this.showModal('small')}}`

Comment: For some reason this will generateInfo, but my modal does not pop up. But when I do just the this.showModal('small'), it will work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this.

Cleaner if you intend on adding more functionality to your click.

```
handleClick = (param) => {
  this.generateInfo()
  this.showModal(param)
}

onClick={this.handleClick('small')}
```